# Python Getting Specific Value From a Function with Multiple Data

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, variables

Following Python code could be used in order to get all values from the function:

```
global a, b, c

a, b, c = function()
```

result:

```
a=5, b=10, c=20
```

How can I get only b value without defining a and c variables?

Comment: Or `_,b,_ = f()`

Comment: @python_user your answer is the first, very simple and it works. How can I get a and c without defining b? Following code does not work: ```function()[0][2]```

Comment: `global a, b, c` is not required

Answer (score 0):

When you want to ignore some values, then use `_`.

```
_,b,_ = function()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the values returned in this way, but the value index should be mentioned.

```
def fun():
    a=1
    b=2
    c=3
    return a,b,c
s = fun()
print(list(s)[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
b = function()[1]
```

to get only the second return value.